# How to open .txt file in netbeans using Mac?

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, processbuilder

I want to open a .txt file using netbeans on Mac.
I want to open the file kind of "Right Click and then Open".
Currently I'm using Following Lines.

```
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder();

    try{
    p.command("TextEdit", "//Users//esna786//Desktop//Testing1//untitled folder//untitled folder//1.txt");
p.start();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

AnyOne to help.

Following is stacktrace

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "TextEdit": error=2, No such file or     directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at comparisonForm.jButton1ActionPerformed(comparisonForm.java:979)
at comparisonForm.access$1300(comparisonForm.java:31)
at comparisonForm$15.actionPerformed(comparisonForm.java:590)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
```

Comment: And what is the exception you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("open", "/Users/esna786/Desktop/Testing1/untitled folder/untitled folder/1.txt").start();
```

In OS X you should use `open` command. It will find appropriate application for open your file passed as argument.

FYI: [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) is detail information about `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: it is giving ioexception.

Comment: Where is `TextEdit` in your OS (requires absolute path to this executable file)? Do you want to open it in Notepad?

Comment: Yes sir I want to open it in notepad in Mac.